# PHP high I/O after a DDoS attack

Tags: nginx, centos, php, io, high-load

I've had a large scale DDoS attack on my website.

After I've enabled captcha challenge through CloudFlare and the attack stopped, PHP's I/O was still loaded at 99%, and the website was working very slow.

Only after a php restart things came back to normal.

My question is, what could be the cause, and how should I prevent that from happening next time?

I was thinking about PHP's sessions that are stored as files, and maybe I should change it to a memory-based database like Redis.

Any other ideas?

I'm running PHP 7.0.33 and nginx/1.15.10 on a CentOs 7.8.2003

PHP config:

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 25000
pm.process_idle_timeout = 20
pm.max_requests = 25000
```